# Shiny Dashboard Categorical Variables and Bar Charts

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, visualization, categorical-data

I'm trying to create an interactive chart to toggle between different variables. One of these variables is numerical (age) but the others are all categorical (gender, department, position). I used code that I found online and the chart to show the distribution of age looks fine, but I can't figure out how to get it to display the categorical variables.
I know I'm missing some things in my code, but I haven't been able to figure out what I need.

Here is the link to the dataset I'm using: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/adityaab1407/employee-productivity-and-satisfaction-hr-data?select=hr_dashboard_data.csv

Here is my current code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "purple",
  dashboardHeader(title = "My dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu()
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(title = "Primary:", status = "primary", solidHeader = T, plotOutput("CPlot"), width = 7),
      box(selectInput("myfile3", "Metric:", c("Age",  "Gender", "Department", "Position")), width = 3)
    ),
      )
    )


server <- function(input, output){
  
  # plot
  Plot <- reactive({
    ggplot(myfile3, aes(x = .data[[input$myfile3]])) +
      geom_histogram(fill="#D55E00", color="#e9ecef", alpha=0.9) +
      labs(
        title = paste0("Distribution of ", paste0(input$myfile3), " employees in workplace"),
        x = req(input$myfile3),
        y = "Count") +
      theme_minimal()
  }) %>% bindEvent(input$myfile3)
  
  output$CPlot <-output$DPlot <-output$EPlot <-output$FPlot <- renderPlot({Plot()})
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It's hard to help you if you don't post a reproducible example. Object 'myfile3' not found! You can select a few rows of that object, and then do a dput() and paste the output here to allow us to try out your app.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `geom_bar()` (barplot) for categorical variables (i.e., all variables except `'Age'`):

```
server <- function(input, output){
  
  # plot
   Plot <- reactive({
     p <- ggplot(myfile3, aes(x = .data[[input$myfile3]]))
     if (input$myfile3 == 'Age') { # numeric
       p <- p + geom_histogram(fill="#D55E00", color="#e9ecef", alpha=0.9)
     } else { # categorical
       p <- p + geom_bar(fill="#D55E00", color="#e9ecef", alpha=0.9)
     }
     p + labs(
      title = paste0("Distribution of ", paste0(input$myfile3), " employees in workplace"),
      x = req(input$myfile3),
      y = "Count") +
     theme_minimal()
   }) %>% bindEvent(input$myfile3)
  
   output$CPlot <-output$DPlot <-output$EPlot <-output$FPlot <- renderPlot({Plot()})
}
```

You could of course check the type (`class`) of the variable and accordingly decide for the type of chart, removing the hardcoding of the name of the variable `'Age'`, here is what you get when you select `'Department'` from the dropdown:

[image]